# Reading sprite x/y location from array 3 steps ago C

Tags: c, arrays, avr

I'm implementing a snake game in C. The snake array is made up of 3x3 sprites. The head of the sprite moves in increments of 1. I'm wondering how I would go about storing the location of the head 3 steps previously so I can then set the next sprite in the array equal to that location and so forth down the length of the snake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
move()
    back3 = back2
    back2 = back1
    back1 = current
    current = ??
```

You could also try a circular buffer with moving pointers. That way you won't have to do all that copying. It's a little harder to implement and debug, though.